# Insertar rol de usuario automaticamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

Tengo esta estructura y estoy trabajando con ASP MVC. Quiero hacer un registro de usuario y lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario se registre, agregarle un rol automáticamente.

Como se ve también, hay distintos usuarios por eso sólo quiero hacer un solo formulario que sirva para todos los usuarios y, según el tipo de usuario, que elija asignarle un rol específicamente cuando se guarde el registro.

[image: Diagrama]

Lo que quiero hacer es, a la hora de guardar el registro del usuario, insertar el valor del `id` del rol que está en la tabla `rol` automáticamente en la tabla `Usuario`, que es la que está relacionada.

Comment: Hola @Kevin. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! No me queda del todo claro si estás preguntando cómo especificar un valor predeterminado en la base de datos, o cómo evaluar el dato ingreso en un formulario para grabarlo en la base. ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta agregando más detalle? Quizás te ayude leer [ask].

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, lo que quiero hacer es que a la hora de guardar el registro del usuario es insertar el valor del id del rol que esta en la tabla rol automáticamente en la tabla Usuario que es la esta relacionada.

Comment: edité la pregunta agregando está información. Dos cosas más: **1** ¿cómo se determina el rol a asignar? ¿se selecciona, siempre es uno predeterminado? y **2** ¿podrás **[edit]** la pregunta agregando el código que tengas hasta ahora, por más que no inserte el rol?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te alcance a entender es que quieres que te guarde el `Rol_id` "automáticamente". Pero ese id tiene que venir de algún lado, como te dijo **Mariano** en la respuesta.

Si tu en el formulario de registro tienes una lista donde selecciona el rol, pues el código anterior te funciona.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id, Nombre, Correo, Password, Rol_id, IDTUSU")] Usuario usuario)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     db.Usuario.Add(usuario);
     db.SaveChanges();                       
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }  
}
```

Pero si quieres asignarles un rol por defecto y siempre el mismo, solo tienes que tener conocimiento del `id` del Rol que esta registrado en la base de datos. Y luego agregarle la siguiente linea antes del `.add`.

```
usuario.Rol_id = aca_va_el_id_del_rol
```

Comment: Si exactamente eso es lo que quiero hacer guardar el rol_id automaticamente pero lo que pasa es que si no seria lo correcto pienso poner algo en el formulario para que se elija el rol por eso agregue la tabla TipoUsuario para con eso validar el usuario que es y asignarle el rol automaticamente y no mostrar en el formulario de registro ese espacio de rol. De hecho el codigo si funciona lo he probado ya pero lo que quiero es que con base en el tipo de usuario le agregue el rol_id automaticamente.

Comment: @Kevin Para ese caso, no seria mas "fácil" quitar la relación de `usuario` con `rol` y hacer otra de `Tipo de usuario` con `rol`.